# Using Dictionary to match codons

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function `codon_pairs(pairs, codonsA, codonsB)` that takes in three arguments; a dictionary `pairs` and two lists, `codonsA` and `codonsB`. The dictionary contains the base pairs and the codon lists contain codon sequences. I am trying to find  the complementary codon sequence in `codonsB` for each codon sequence in `codonsA`, and return matching pairs like the following:

```
pairs = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
codonsA = ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']
codonsB = ['TAA', 'CTA', 'AAC', 'TTC', 'AGA', 'CCC', 'CCG', 'GTA']

print(codons_pairs(pairs, condonsA, codonsB))

[('AAG', 'TTC'), ('GAT', 'CTA'), ('TTG', 'AAC'), ('CAT', 'GTA'), ('GGC',   'CCG'), ('ATT', 'TAA'), ('TCT', 'AGA')]
```

The first item in the 2-tuple is a codon from `codonsA` and the second item is a matching codon from `codonsB`. For example, the sequences **AAG** (`codonsA[0]`) and **TCC** (`codonsB[3]`) are matching pairs, as the base pair of A is T, and the base pair of G is C, highlighted in the `pairs` dictionary.

On the flip side, if a matching pair cannot be found, it will be omitted from the final result.

This is what I have so far:

```
pairs = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
codonsA = ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']
codonsB = ['TAA', 'CTA', 'AAC', 'TTC', 'AGA', 'CCC', 'CCG', 'GTA']

def codons_pairs(pairs, codonsA, codonsB):

    for A in codonsA:
        for B in codonsB:
            for i in A:
                for j in B:
```

I'm just not sure how to check pairs between `codonsA` and `codonsB`, with regard to a dictionary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `codonsB` to a `set()` for fast checking (O(1) membership tests, no need for nested loops), then map each codon from `A` through your `pairs` mapping and test the result against the set:

```
def codons_pair(pairs, codonsA, codonsB):
    codonsB = set(codonsB)
    for codon in codonsA:
        complement = ''.join([pairs[base] for base in codon])
        if complement in codonsB:
            yield (codon, complement)
```

The above is a generator function; it'll yield each match as it finds them. You could convert the resulting generator to a list with the `list()` function, or just iterate over the function.

Demo:

```
>>> pairs = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
>>> codonsA = ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']
>>> codonsB = ['TAA', 'CTA', 'AAC', 'TTC', 'AGA', 'CCC', 'CCG', 'GTA']
>>> list(codons_pair(pairs, codonsA, codonsB))
[('AAG', 'TTC'), ('GAT', 'CTA'), ('TTG', 'AAC'), ('CAT', 'GTA'), ('GGC', 'CCG'), ('ATT', 'TAA'), ('TCT', 'AGA')]
```